# In a salesforce template, how can I recursively check a parent property?

Tags: salesforce

I'm a developer but I haven't touched salesforce before.

I've been given this:

```
<td class="textAlignRight">
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__LogoURL__c<>''}"><img src="{!relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__LogoURL__c}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
</td>
```

and told that rather than putting in the logo of OwnerCompany, I should be putting in the logo of Parent, but if the LogoURL property of Parent is blank, I should put in the LogoURL of it's parent, and so on, until I find a logo or there are no more parents, in which case I should put the OwnerCompany LogoURL in.

I'm having trouble googling the language that salesforce uses. Does anyone have any ideas how I can solve this? Some kind of function call to a method with a loop?

Edit:

Apparently it needs to do this:

```
Invoice > Account > LogoURL

Invoice > Account > ParentAccount > LogoURL

Invoice > Account > ParentAccount > ParentAccount > LogoURL
```

etc.

where Invoice is the relatedToType.

So I guess I need to check LogoURL, if it's blank check ParentAccount, if that's blank, check ParentAccount.ParentAccount, etc. and if the last one of those is blank, use

Invoice > OwnerCompany > LogoURL

Comment: Is the API name of the "Parent" field you are referring to something like "c2g__Parent__c"?

Comment: Okay, I've found the property list, the fields are all named as above, there is an Owner field which is the closest I can see to Parent. If we assume there is a Parent field...

Comment: The `c2g__` portion of the field name refers to the namespace of the field - sounds like the field was added with a managed package (possibly from the Salesforce.com AppExchange). The `__c` refers to the fact that it's a custom field.

The `Owner` field is a reference to the user owning that particular record; I highly doubt that there would be a LogoURL field on the User object. What datatype is the `relatedTo` variable in this case?

Comment: `relatedToType="c2g__codaInvoice__c"` but I can't find how to view that object through the UI. I think I need to talk to the guy who uses salesforce

Comment: I guess if I can figure out how to call some external code, like a function call, I can simply write a do while loop and all will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this...this code is assuming that the `c2g__OwnerCompany__r` field is pointing to an Account record, which in turn has its own `c2g_OwnerCompany__r` field pointing to a parent account (if it has one). VisualForce is not really built for this this type of recursion, and I think you'll see why:

```
<apex:variable var="parentLogo" value="{!relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__LogoURL__c}" />
<apex:variable var="parentLogo2" value="{!relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__LogoURL__c}" />
<apex:variable var="parentLogo3" value="{!relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__OwnerCompany__r.c2g__LogoURL__c}" />
<td class="textAlignRight">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!parentLogo<>''}">
        <img src="{!parentLogo}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!AND(NOT(parentLogo<>''), parentLogo2<>'')}">
        <img src="{!parentLogo2}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!AND(NOT(parentLogo<>''), NOT(parentLogo2<>'') parentLogo3<>'')}">
        <img src="{!parentLogo3}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</td>
```

I wouldn't really recommend this approach, as it quickly makes a mess out of your VF page and also has a limit on how many levels down you can start at.

A alternative solution would be to handle this in your controller class, where have much more control over the recursion. It's worth noting that Salesforce imposes strict limits on the number of times you can hit the database in the context of a single call, so you'll want to figure out a way to restrict the number of queries that this makes. I would probably only use this if you can guarantee that you only have a couple levels of parent accounts and that there are no circular references:

```
public String getLogoUrl() {
    String logo;
    Account acc= [select Id, c2g__OwnerCompany__c, c2g__LogoURL__c from Account where Id = :relatedTo.c2g__OwnerCompany__c];
    // running SOQL queries inside of loops is most certainly NOT a Salesforce best practice
    while ( true ) {
        logo = acc.c2g__LogoURL__c;
        if ( acc.c2g__OwnerCompany__c != null )
            acc = [select Id, c2g__OwnerCompany__c, c2g__LogoURL__c from Account where Id = :acc.c2g__OwnerCompany__c];
        else
            break;
    }
    return logo;
}
```

This in turn simplifies your VF page to something similar to what you started out with. The `logoUrl` variable will automatically be populated when the page loads by a call to `getLogoUrl` in the controller:

```
<td class="textAlignRight">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!AND(NOT(ISNULL(logoUrl)), logoUrl<>'')}">
        <img src="{!logoUrl}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</td>
```

Comment: Wow thanks for such a comprehensive reply! I don't know how controllers and whatnot works in salesforce, but this gives me a good starting point if not the solution. I was just given the edit template page and told to take a look. I'm sure I can make this work. Thanks for taking the time to come up with the answer :)

Comment: Just an update, this code worked great and is much appreciated :) The only odd thing was I had to use `c2g__OwnerCompany__r` instead of `c2g__OwnerCompany__c`, I don't know what the r means, but it was used elsewhere in the code for rendering other details. Couldn't find any reference of it. Mysterious! Thanks again though!